# How to customize tab bar button and tab bar selected color?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I want customize tab bar..Not a gray color..How to customize tab bar ? How to change tab bar selected background color (default: blue color)?

Answer (score 5):

You either use private APIs, which will cause your app to be rejected from the App Store
or you write your own tab bar control.

Answer (score 3):

Try This in your app deletegate.m file

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```